# Counting elements in a list with a specific value with Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

Suppose I have an array of objects or dicts, I want to count the number of objects in the array with an attribute with a specific value.

Jinja already provides a mechanism for iterating over elements that have a specific value:

```
{% set list = [dict(a=1),dict(a=2),dict(a=1)] %}
{{ list }}<br/>
{% for e in list if e.a == 1 %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

I simply want to know how many times the for loop would be evaluated.

The best I've been able to come up with is to use the `loop.last` variable to evaluate my expression on the last iteration of the above loop

```
{% set list = [dict(a=1),dict(a=2),dict(a=1)] %}
{{ list }}<br/>
{% for e in list if e.a == 1 %}
  {% if loop.last %}
    list contains {{ loop.index }} elements with a=1
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

this, however, won't work if the number of matching items is zero. I can obviously put the conditional inside the loop to fix that issue

```
{% set list = [dict(a=1),dict(a=2),dict(a=1)] %}
{{ list }}<br/>
{% for e in list %}
  {% if e.a == 1 %}
    {% set count = count|d(0) + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if loop.last %}
    list contains {{ count }} elements with a=1
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which will now be fine as long as the list isn't empty (in my case the list is never empty).

The other obvious answer is to add a function to the global context that could be used to perform this calculation, but I'm surprised such functionality doesn't already exist.

My goal is to change the style of certain table headers when particular values are present in the table.

Answer (score 9):

You can use jinja's capabilities to achieve your goal in a concise way, without using loops:

```
{{ yourlist | selectattr("a", "equalto", 1) | list | count }}
```

Note that you have to use the *list* filter in order to count.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.10 one can use [namespaces](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#assignments) to do what you want to do:

```
{% set ns = namespace(count=0) %}
{% for state in states -%}
  {% if state.some_test() -%}
    {% set ns.count = ns.count + 1 -%}
  {% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
Total count: {{ ns.count }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also `loop.length`, have you looked at using that?